# How can I bypass exe4j?

Tags: java, windows, jar, reverse-engineering, exe4j

I want to launch this game in another jvm of choice (IKVM) but i cannot find a way around this due to exe4j.

I understand that exej4 EXEs use the bundled jre components (in a subfolder) as DLLs, so I am unabl to find some command line to spoof.

I have found a configuration file in my user profile folder, but i am not sure on how to use it...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LaunchConfig className="em.entry.EntryRedactedGame" methodName="main" runDir="." downloadDir="update/download" extractDir="update/extract" resourcesPath="resource-config.xml">
  <classpath>
    <string value="game.jar" />
    <string value="lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar" />
    <string value="lib/jinput.jar" />
    <string value="lib/lwjgl.jar" />
    <string value="lib/lwjgl_util.jar" />
    <string value="lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar" />
    <string value="lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar" />
    <string value="lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" />
  </classpath>
</LaunchConfig>
```

I have figured out only a part of the command to execute game.jar

> java -cp game.jar;lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar;lib/jinput.jar;lib/lwjgl.jar;lib/lwjgl_util.jar;lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar;lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar em.entry.EntryRedactedGame

as I get this exception when I run it:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/Element
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom.Element
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 7 more

So the real question is **How do I reconstruct th complete command line to java.exe ?**

Comment: It depends ALOT on whether the jar files are packaged within the exe or not.  exe4j doesn't embed the JRE internally, but as you say, it executes the specified JRE using the .dll's

Comment: game.jar is along with game.exe

Comment: Try using java -jar game.jar

Comment: It says: `no main manifest attribute, in game.jar`